# Plug mongodb into wso2 esb

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-esb

Does somebody tried to plug MongoDB as Datasource inside WSO2 ESB ?
Indeed, I want to use MongoDB as MessageStore for my ESB.

Tks
Nicolas

Answer (score -1):

This is not available out of the box with WSO2 ESB. But you should be able to write a custom message store by extending the AbstractMessageStore class. Following two links say it is possible.
http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2012/01/wso2-esb-tips-tricks-08-message-stores.html
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Custom+Message+Store

I already went through the two available message store implementations (in-memory and JMS). It does not seem as easy as writing a custom mediator. But it is possible.